# on Hyperledger-explorer when insert some big data have RangeError: "size" argument must not be larger than 2147483647

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-explorer

I have set up a Hyperledger-explorer(v3.2) + fabric network (v1.1.0) on a Ubuntu 16.04 .

Everything works fine but when I add some big transactions to my fabric, Hyperledger-explorer through this error:

> ```
> buffer.js:224
>     throw err;
>     ^
> RangeError: "size" argument must not be larger than 2147483647
>     at Function.Buffer.alloc (buffer.js:233:3)
>     at new Buffer (buffer.js:156:19)
>     at module.exports.Reader.addChunk (/home/bcadmin/sunbc/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/packet-reader/index.js:35:21)
>     at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/bcadmin/sunbc/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:110:18)
>     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
>     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
>     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
>     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
>     at TCP.onread (net.js:597:20)
> ```